# Merge MP4 files with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two MP4 files that one contain video and audio, and one contains only video,

I have to combine both files – meaning, play both files at the same time. I do not want to concatenate them (add one after another).

So how can I do this?

Comment: Do you want the videos to play side-by-side?

Comment: I want to play video side-by-side.